# WordPress creating custom roles for authors and managers

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website creating with WordPress. I need to add some custom user roles and custom access. So this is what I want:

1. I want to add two custom roles for Authors. `Worker 1` and `Worker 2`
2. Then I should add two more role named: `Supervisor 1` and `Supervisor 2`
3. Users assigned to `Worker 1` and `Worker 2` roles can publish new posts but they suppose to see only their own posts in admin panel lists.
4. Users in `Supervisor 1` and `Supervisor 2` are managers. `Supervisor 1` role should only access and see list of all published posts that created by `Worker 1` role, and `Supervisor 2` should only see all posts that created by `Worker 2` role.

This is my code:

```
// Add custom roles
function add_custom_roles() {
    // Add Worker 1 role
    add_role( 'worker_1', 'Worker 1', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'publish_posts' => true,
    ) );

    // Add Worker 2 role
    add_role( 'worker_2', 'Worker 2', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'publish_posts' => true,
    ) );

    // Add Supervisor 1 role
    add_role( 'supervisor_1', 'Supervisor 1', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'publish_posts' => false,
        'read_private_posts' => true,
    ) );

    // Add Supervisor 2 role
    add_role( 'supervisor_2', 'Supervisor 2', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'publish_posts' => false,
        'read_private_posts' => true,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_roles' );

// Limit posts visibility for Worker 1 and Worker 2
function limit_post_visibility( $query ) {
    // Check if current user is a Worker 1 or Worker 2
    if ( in_array( 'worker_1', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) || in_array( 'worker_2', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
        // Retrieve only posts created by the current user
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_post_visibility' );
```

This is currently limit `Worker 1` and `Worker 2` to see their own posts, but `Supervisor 1` and `Supervisor 2` are free to see all roles posts. This part should be fixed.

Comment: You'll need to add handling for those in your `limit_post_visibility` then. When the user has the role `Supervisor 1`, then you will need to fetch the IDs of all users that have the role `Worker 1`, and feed those IDs into your query via the `author__in` parameter.